# CME SDL WEB - Modify behaviour select item

Tags: cme, web8.5

A customer requested to modify the behaviour of the interface of the CMS.

When you want to select an image to link it to another component using "Select Item" window, he wants to modify the default folder that is opened in the left side depending of the component that you opened.

My question is: is there an option to intercept the functionality of this screen to modify his behaviour (marked in red)?

[image]